# Ajax to update a value in a table not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ajax call to call POST of a model return 404 error
Not sure why there are 2 post calls made.
Is the route the issue?

show.html.erb:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var apiKey = '<%= @api_key %>';
      var sessionId = '<%= @room.session_id %>';
      var token = '<%= @token %>';
      var room = '<%= @room %>';
    </script>


    <%= debug @room %>

    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
    <script>

      var session;
      var connection_id;
      var connectionCount;

      initializeSession();

      // Connect to the session
      session.connect(token, function(error) {
         // If the connection is successful, publish to the session
         console.log("session connected")
         if (error) {
           handleError(error);
         } else {
         session.publish(publisher, handleError);
       }
      });

     session.on("connectionCreated", function(event) {
      console.log("connectionCreated");
      console.log(room.id);
      connectionCount++;
      // jqueryFunction("Call from js to jquery");
       $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        data: JSON.stringify({ room: {name: 'New_room'}, _method:'put' }),
        url: "/rooms/" + room.id + "/connected",
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function( msg )
    {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

   }
   </script>
   room GET    /rooms/:id(.:format)         rooms#show
              PATCH  /rooms/:id(.:format)         rooms#update
              PUT    /rooms/:id(.:format)         rooms#update
              DELETE /rooms/:id(.:format)         rooms#destroy


def update
    # @room.update_attributes(params[:name])
end
```

Error:
 POST http://localhost:3000/room/6 404 (Not Found)
 POST http://localhost:3000/rooms/room 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails generate `put` request by inject the hidden field in the form with name of `_method` and the value `put`, like this

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

so you need to change to this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "script",
    url: '/rooms/5',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {rooms:{name: "New_room"}, _method: "put"}
 }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That did get rid of one of the POST errors. But I still get the http://localhost:3000/rooms/room 404 (Not Found). This is request is also generated by the same ajax function. Because if I remove the ajax function, I don't see that error.

Comment: Also the value for `name` in `Room` model for that particular room is not updated. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Could you provide the request logs? Just the logs when you call the ajax.

Comment: Started POST "/rooms/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-05 08:02:02 -0800
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/rooms/6"):

Comment: What if the data attribute change to `data: JSON.stringify({ room: {name: 'New_room'}, _method:'put' })`, I think the variable is `room` not `rooms`.

Comment: I modified the code as per your suggestion. That works like a charm, thank you so much! But the current problem I am having is that the `Room` object is nil. It is a rails view object and it is not available for javascript. How can I pass the `Room` object to javascript? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Figured it out. `   var room_id = <%= @room.id %>` is the way to pass an object from rails view to js